# I get a deprecation warning when I use 'stub_chain' of gem 'rspec-mock'

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-mocks

I'm making a mock for some Object with RSpec and rspec-mocks.
What I dis is the below.

In Spec file

```
describe 'foo' do
  before do
    Mock.start
  end
end
```

In Mock file

```
module Mock
  def self.start
    SomeClass.stub_chain(:foo).and_return(Mock.mock_create)
  end

  def self.mock_create
    return json
  end
end
```

But if I use `stub_chain`, the below deprecation warning occurs.

```
Using `stub_chain` from rspec-mocks' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` instead.
```

Do you have any ideas which solve this warning?
The `allow` method looks unuseful because I wanna code like `Object.something_instead_of_stub_chain(:create).and_return(Mock.mock_create)`.

Answer (score 2):

The new way of doing it is

```
   expect(SomeClass).to receive_message_chain(:foo, :bar, :baz).and_return(something_here)
   # or if not a chain
   expect(SomeClass).to receive(:foo).and_return(something_here)
```

Instead of `expect` you may use `allow`. Those will not fail if the method is not called at all but will return specified values when called.